# why the http response body is not decode even if the Content-Encoding is gzip

Tags: http, charles-proxy

after I create a request by postman, i use charles to get the response,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date,x-fc-request-id,x-fc-error-type,x-fc-code-checksum,x-fc-invocation-duration,x-fc-max-memory-usage,x-fc-log-result,x-fc-invocation-code-version
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: accept-encoding
X-Fc-Code-Checksum: 6560052838157534644
X-Fc-Instance-Id: c-64537eee-a21501c647424911964a
X-Fc-Invocation-Duration: 16
X-Fc-Invocation-Service-Version: LATEST
X-Fc-Max-Memory-Usage: 51.81
X-Fc-Request-Id: 1-64537fec-dcdfb76685b36ac4eb3d6825
Date: Thu, 04 May 2023 09:50:36 GMT
Content-Length: 940
Connection: keep-alive

H4sIAAAAAAAAA72WTW/bPAyA/4vPoSNRpCT6tsMw7LBbdtmLHqivNkDWBom7YSj63185HbZdVhgLUMDwpyw+Ih/Jfhq+1lmH6Wk53j2UYRo+vN8Nm+HhWE867x/u+52tHvfbVud89+5w+PTj49fbc29x1Nv9/e0w3T8eDs+boejSz39Pw355/PPk8+nQT4e7eT6ep+32+JggJhJtDqVpJRFV9k4kNC5kfFQaTziW+m17W+9/Epy3MSRbqjXgSDNQRoYoMUIWaSkYbVgcmPHYcTZvE8y+ZTB8y2DuEuxmM5xnnR97JYfzY871vJQ8n6rO9d3cb6LBnnIGgzs0E+LEPBLyl97qIhT6UcjiZmj703nuyvR33lSD/eJyRmtsSf0NhwmIbQAhDJBj0eKztS3o8Lz57eoi8x9D/677eX/p7u9Dp8nRKBh/Df2lj9/jfrm+8GBLKQsZoB4fKLGAMCsUG7TmYJzz7jWeejo9nF6joTAZHNmYNTS1lIAhEvhSPZAXhmSUgFNhds6qc+VaGte1ELeGhnwuLroIiBaBHJYuiSw77IIYQrL2OhqZUMYosoZGFKnVFCHl1HNjM0IKbGBJWGNbMaZwFQ2byfkxrKPxPiTnTYVc+o5SjaAxLjIX1Vr7pKntCho72TChGb3gqtxkdkaou0u9XOS5QkrBQyscYqycfclXzSq7LChGRuNoDY9jTL6kArYmCyQh96pxgpZirZqbxPKqOa/zuJ2xU9+IRqZVJmMw1DR2Ciu9WowWIloHzQhrrD465Ct5FoF4dLIqPwVJo2kePGYBCqG8kHlfMzYTJcsVq6DbWTf1ra871vtV+XHWc0MEiaHPdBsEFKNC5cqmBmdKNf9qM+0MTSxd6JHCquxYjU2C7bo0Dd0eKqASFLzjSBhbF6hX6+a5fxIvgZefm5vn/wHoKEHpOQkAAA=
```

it obviously correct,  the body is encoded by gizp, provide the correct `Content-Encoding: gzip`,
but the body in charles is not decoded automatically and there is a error in postman like "Error: incorrect header check
"

there should be a decoded body

Comment: Curious to know why do you need to check response in Charles when you can view the response directly in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the content of that response using [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true,false)Gunzip()&input=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) confirms that the content is indeed JSON that has been gzipped and encoded as base64.

[image: Screenshot of decoding steps in Cyberchef]

This means that the Content-Encoding header is missing the base64 encoding probably should be `Content-Encoding: gzip,base64` instead.